# Using Bootstrap Modal window as PartialView will not show on screen, but appears in Chrome dev tools

Tags: asp.net, .net, bootstrap-modal

The weirdest thing is happening to me. So I have a parent page which is basically a list. On every item I have a delete button which would trigger a modal within a partial view to popup as to confirm if the user want's to delete it. As the title tells, it does not pop up, but when I use the Google Chrome Dev tools, I can see that the modal has actually poped up, but is not showing up on screen.

**This is my modal from my parent page**:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="delete-association">
            @Html.Partial("_DeleteAssociationModal")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this little javascript method that is triggered **on the click of the delete button to call my controller and have it return to me the partial modal**:

```
function OpenModal(associationId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: associationId },
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDeleteModal", "Associations")',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#delete-association').html(data);
            $('#delete-modal').modal('show');
        },
    })
};
```

**This is the method called in my controller that returns the partial :**

```
public ActionResult GetDeleteModal(int id)
    {
        var association = // getting the info for the object to be deleted

        return PartialView("_DeleteAssociationModal", association);
    }
```

This is so weird.. As I said, I can see the modal in the Chrome tools, but it does not pop up...

Help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: There must be a CSS class that is resetting the z-index of that modal, try adding a style z-index of high value and see what happens

Comment: @Bosco, thank you for the reply, I tried adding a z-index, but it's still behaving the same way... any other ideas?

Comment: Using your browser, inspect the element on top of the modal and make sure that the z-index is more than what the element has

Comment: By on top you mean the div that comes before it in my html file?

Comment: I meant when it was supposed to pop-up and never did, there mus be an element showing on the page at that time, check for the z-index of that element. Hope you are using bootstrap.css

Comment: @Bosco the z-index has a value of 1050

Comment: What is the z-index on the modal? Without this @Html.Partial("_DeleteAssociationModal"), does it show?, Also try populating the modal from button click as <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

Comment: Adding data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" and changing my anchor to a button made it all work! Thank you so much @Bosco

Answer (score 0):

The button that was calling my method was actually an anchor tag. I changed that to a button and added :

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal"
```

to it's properties and it worked just fine!

Credit goes to @Bosco

Comment: anchor tags works too, you need to put the target as href like <a href="#delete-modal"></a>